# Best Way to Handle Meta Information in a SQL Database

Tags: database-design

I've got a database where I want to store `user` information and `user_meta` information.

The reason behind setting it up in this way was because the `user_meta` side may change over time and I would like to do this without disrupting the master `user` table.

If possible, I would like some advice on how to best set up this meta data table.

I can either set it as below:

```
+----+---------+----------+--------------------+
| id | user_id | key      | value              |
+----+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 1  | 1       | email    | test@testemail.com |
| 2  | 1       | name     | user name          |
| 3  | 1       | address  | test address       |
...
```

Or, I can set it as below:

```
+----+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| id | user_id | email              | name               | address      |
+----+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 1  | 1       | test@testemail.com | user name          | test address |
```

Obviously, the top verison is more flexible, but the bottom version is space saving and perhaps more efficient, returning all the data as a single record.

Which is the best way to go about this?
Or, am I going about this completely wrong and there's another way I've not thought of?

Comment: It may help your research to know that your first example is known as EVA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). It is often considered an anti-pattern from a relational perspective, but there are times whe it is the only viable approach.